# Angular [ngStyle] or [style.background-color] not working with '!important'

Tags: angular, angular-material

In both situations, using '!important' it doesn't work as expected. If I remove the '!important', the background-color receives the change but it doesn't change cause of inheritance. But I want it to be '!important!'.

without '!important':

```
element.style {
    margin-right: 5px;
    *background-color: 'green';* (line-through)
}
```

with '!important':

```
element.style {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

I have already tryed:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': myColor + ' !important'}"
```

and

```
[attr.style]="'background-color: ' + myColor  + ' !important'"
```

and

```
[style.background-color]="myColor  + '!important'"
```

The problem is that I'm generating buttons dynamically and during the generation I want to apply the background-color. That wya I can't use `@ViewChild`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `[ngStyle]` not works with `!important`. Instead of using `ngStyle`, you can implement it using `[ngClass]`.
2. To set values to `[attr.style]`, you need to make the style value to `TrustStyle` as follows.

```
[attr.style]="('font-size:' + actions.fontSize + '% !important') | safeStyle"
```

Here is the `safeStyle` pipe content.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safeStyle' })
export class SafeStylePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }
  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try to use the safeStyle pipe. But about the ngClass, I need to create the background color dynamically. For example, lets say that ´myColor´ var retrieves from the backend with '#33ab44' value. I don't have a class with thist background color. Got it?

Comment: Derek, where did you find this information about safeStyle pipe?

Comment: I have met that issue before. ;) And if it works, can you pls approve my answer? @GM-atteoni

Comment: Another question. If I want to use more than one style with '!important'? am I able to use [attr.style] more than once in the element?

Comment: Yeah, it will be possible.

Comment: I've tryed but when I use two time [arr.style] in the same element it only accepts the last one.

Comment: Not mean of using two times, Update like this. `[arr.style]="('font-size: 3px; background-image: red') | safeStyle"`

Comment: Thank you, dude. U are awesome.